Google Street View in Google Earth - clickable
I am using Google Earth Pro. I have added a layer using KML.
Is there a way to make the KML layer clickable when I move to Street View.

I don't believe you can make it clickable, but you could try adding place markers (pin icon) to different areas which you can add descriptions of areas to and mark important locations. If you could reply with more information about what you are interested in doing I may be able to help more. The below link can walk you through the pinning process.
https://support.google.com/earth/answer/148142?hl=en

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
